# Perform a segue using a button in a custom cell and passing on an object

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to write a tablet tracking app for my mother but I'm having an issue I'm using an edit button to access a static table view but it is refusing to pass on the medicine object.

I need to be able to get the indexPath in prepare(for:sender:) and I'd usually use tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow and then use the row to pull the right one from the array but as I'm using a button that's not possible.

I've tried using the tag to store the row, I've tried a protocol as suggested in other answers here but I've had no success. The app still crashes when I'm trying to go to the edit screen. I have my current code below, gone through too many iterations to list them all

```
@IBAction func editButtonTapped(_sender: UIButton) {
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero to self.tableView)
    buttonIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
    preformSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: sender)
}
```

and my prepare(for:sender:) code is as follows

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! MedicineDetailTableViewController
        let selectedMedicine = medicines[(buttonIndexPath?.row)!]
        destination.medicine = selectedMedicine
    }
}
```

I apologise if this is something stupid that I'm missing but I'm at wit's end.

Comment: Downvotes? I thought SO was supposed to be 'nicer'. This is a genuine question, and the poster has made an effort. Anyway, poster: you should post actual code (what you posted there won't actually compile), and the stacktrace of where you crash. I bet you're crashing in the 'let selectedMedicine=' line, and buttonIndexPath is nil...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I'm following these steps:

**1)** Add 'Your Edit Button' into your `UITableViewCell` and create IBOutlet.

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var yourEditButton: UIButton!
}
```

**2)** In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, assign button tag as index.

```
 cell.yourEditButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

**3)** Create IBAction in your View Controller. Open storyboard and connect "your edit button" with this IBAction function.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

    let selectedMedicine: Medicine? //your global Medicine variable

    @IBAction func editButtonTapped(_sender: UIButton) {
        //now you can access selected row via sender.tag

        selectedMedicine = medicines[sender.tag]
        preformSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: nil)
    }
 }
```

**Finally:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetails" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! MedicineDetailTableViewController
        destination.medicine = selectedMedicine
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work but such code breaks any separation between logic and UI code. In this case cell "know" about business models and performs app navigation. Solution from next comment will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup delegate for for custom cell with function like

```
func buttonTapped(_ sender: UITableViewCell)
```

Then You can use sender to get `IndexPath` with `indexPath(for:)` on `tableView` and perform segue.

Then Your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` can look like this:

```
tableView(_:cellForRowAt:){
   //setup other stuff and dequeue cell
   cell.delegate = self
   return cell

}
```